# How to track clicks with Ahoy Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've installed the Ahoy gem for Rails, but I can't figure out where to add in the ahoy.trackClicks() bit of code to track clicks.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hi as per the [documentation](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy) you can track the number of clicks with this method
 `ahoy.trackClicks();`
And you can use this method in your `ApplicationController`  or in any controller where you want to use it.
Cheers!